# MongoDB ODBC DSN Configuration

Tags: mongodb, powerbi

I want to setup this DSN, i had installed the odbc mongodb driver.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M91y.jpg)

where i put the data, this is freeze, and not responding.
I am trying with differents data but is the same.
I need this configuration cause i wanna connect powerbi with my mongodb database.
ALso i wanna know what is the correct ip cause i have one ip for each cluster but i have a url like a main server information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Mongo's guide on setting up the DSN: https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/tutorial/create-system-dsn/, and more generally, the quick start guide: https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/local-quickstart/

Some potential fixes:

- make sure you have the mongosqld process running
- make sure you enter a database in the database field
- make sure your port is correct: you can get it from the mongosqld process logs. Note: this is not the port where mongodb itself is running.
- Mongo provides two drivers: ANSI and UNICODE. Although ANSI supposedly has better performance, try the UNICODE one and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score -2):

I've once created a connection between mongodb and PowerBI using R. Get data through R script and write a tiny script like that;

library(mongolite)
m<-mongo(collection="YourCollectionName",db = "YourDBName",url = "mongodb://YourHostName", verbose = F)
Query<-m$find(query = "{}", fields = "{\"_id\":0}", sort = "{}", skip = 0, limit = 0, handler = NULL, pagesize = 1000)

ps. Before running install R on server and install mongolite package with=>
install.packages("mongolite")